# How to Create Excel Pivot Table to R

Tags: r, excel, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table from my data set in excel to R.  I have been following this tutorial on how to do this: http://excel2r.com/pivot-tables-in-r-basic-pivot-table-columns-and-metrics/ .  I have used the codes mentioned in this tutorial by replacing it with my own data variables,  but I keep getting an error message noting: Error: **`select()` doesn't handle lists.**

What does this error message mean and how I can I fix this?

The R-Script I have been using from the tutorial is:

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

```
pivot <- df %>%
        select(Product.Category, Region, Customer.Segment, Sales)%>%
        group_by(Product.Category, Region, Customer.Segment) %>%
        summarise(TotalSales = sum(Sales))
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

By your error message: "select() doesn't handle lists.", I supose that your object called **df** isn't a dataframe.

Maybe you have a dataframe inside a list.

Try this in your R console:

```
class(df)
```

If the class is a list, you need take off the dataframe from the list. You can do this by the position. Probably in the first position. `df[[1]]`

The functions that you are using, works only for dataframes in general. (And tibbles, that is a another type of dataframe)

Like this example:

[image]

I hope it works for you.

And, for the next time, try to make an reproducible example.
You could at least print your dataframe original, before try to use these functions, that way I could help you efficiently.